# How to use argparse with json files in python

Tags: python, json, argparse

I'm working on a project in Python and I was trying set up some arguments with `argparse`. When I type one of those in the terminal, I get some info from a JSON file but I cant figure out how to do it. So far I got these things:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "ac",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "63%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acv",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "37%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acf",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "48%"
    },
    {
      "name": "ach",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "10%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acj",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "23%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acq",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "65%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
        {
      "name": "bcc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "25%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcx",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "4%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcn",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "50%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcm",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "35%"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my JSON file and these are the arguments in my `.py`:

```
#argparse parameters config
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f",
                    "--fullreport",
                    help="printing the full report",
                    default="*")
parser.add_argument("-g",
                    "--graphreport",
                    help="printing the graph report",
                    default="*")
parser.add_argument("-s",
                    "--services",
                    help="services to be test",
                    default=["*"])
parser.add_argument("-d",
                    "--diskusage",
                    help="see the disk usage")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I have more code but it is to print all the JSON file with a with open and a for instances but what I want is to print for example just the services using the argument `-s`.

Comment: Do a `print(args)` to see what the parser has done (assuming it doesn't raise an error and quite).  One of those attributes, such as `args.s` should be file name.  Just use the Python `json` file reader to load and parse that file.

Comment: is that the full json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```py
def print_service_names(data):
    print('Services:')
    for service in data['services']:
        print(service['name'])

def print_service_disk_usages(data):
    print('Disk Usage:')
    for service in data['services']:
        print(f'{service["name"]}:\t{service["disk usage"]}')

print_service_names(json_data)
print_service_disk_usages(json_data)
```

Output:

```
Services:
ac
acc
acv
acf
ach
acj
acq
bc
bcc
bcx
bcn
bcm

Disk Usage:
ac:     20%
acc:    63%
acv:    37%
acf:    48%
ach:    10%
acj:    23%
acq:    65%
bc:     20%
bcc:    25%
bcx:    4%
bcn:    50%
bcm:    35%
```

If you plan on doing some more advanced things with the data, you can use comprehensions to reshape it:

```py
# format the data with comprehensions
service_names = [service['name']
                 for service in json_data['services']]
disk_usage = {service['name']: service['disk usage']
              for service in json_data['services']}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(service_names)
pprint(disk_usage)
```

Output:

```py
['ac',
 'acc',
 'acv',
 'acf',
 'ach',
 'acj',
 'acq',
 'bc',
 'bcc',
 'bcx',
 'bcn',
 'bcm']

{'ac': '20%',
 'acc': '63%',
 'acf': '48%',
 'ach': '10%',
 'acj': '23%',
 'acq': '65%',
 'acv': '37%',
 'bc': '20%',
 'bcc': '25%',
 'bcm': '35%',
 'bcn': '50%',
 'bcx': '4%'}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tenacious B! I have a question!! I got an error when run the program with this code."NameError: name 'json_data' is not defined" I imagine that I have to define some Json_data.

other question is how can I use this code with argparse. example : I want to put on the terminal "name.py -s" to print the services or -d to print disk usage. it is that possible?

Comment: you're going to need to change the variable names to fit the rest of your code

Comment: @MaximilianoCorrea `json_data` is just a variable I assigned to the string of your the json in your question